# Contents of Dictionary not accessible outside of NSURLConnection Function

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

I have a function that takes in a string and returns a dictionary that is populated through a URL request. My function assigns strings to JSON objects, retrieved using `SwiftyJSON`. The properties are updated, but upon exiting the `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` function, they are unaccessible.

So for the 1, 2, and 3 `println`s, the array prints out correctly, but not on 4. Here is the code:

```
func parseJSON(id:String) -> Dictionary<String, JSON> {
    var properties = [String:JSON]()
    var postEndpoint = "http://localhost:3000/properties/\(id)"
    var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: {
        (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if let anError = error {
            println("error calling GET on /properties/\(id)")
        }
        else {
            let post = JSON(data: data)
            if let title = post["name"].string {
                for (index: String, subJson:JSON) in post {
                    properties[index] = subJson
                }
                println("1: \(properties)")
            }
            else {
                println("error parsing response from POST on /posts")
            }
            println("2 \(properties)")
        }
        println("3 \(properties)")
    })
    println("4 \(properties)")
    return ds1Properties
}
```

It is also important to note that the 4 prints out before the 1, 2, and 3, which makes me think the `NSURLConnection` is called later, so the return value isn't updated before it leaves the `parseJSON` function.

Comment: Your web request is being done asynchronously.  4 is printed first because the web request takes time.  Once the request completes, the completion block is called.

Comment: So how can I prevent the function from returning without having waited for the web request to complete?

Comment: You should not delay it from returning. That is very very very bad, the worse thing to do. You should go and do a bit of background reading on asynchonrous vs synchronous then ask more questions. At the moment your knowledge is too basic to be able to give you solutions. You need to prepare first.

Comment: There are many many tools available for you to properly handle asynchronous requests. You can call a function from your completion block that will do whatever you need done with the JSON. You can post a notification that your json is complete and have a listener handle it. However, things like network calls are asynchronous for a reason, and you should NOT try to fight it.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I am familiar with the concept of synchronous and asynchronous requests. When I said "prevent from returning" I meant what alternative method should I use to be able to access the data before the function returns. I am going to redo this using a synchronous call. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn what asynchronous means and how to program asynchronously.

With asynchronous code, each line is not executed one after the other, they are executed in parallel.

When you call parseJSON() it will finish and return immediately, but within it you have called sendAsynchronousRequest. This starts another thread running in parallel (do you know what a thread is?). This thread might not finish for several seconds. Therefore steps 1, 2, and 3 might not execute until several seconds after step 4.

You cannot put an asynchonrous function inside a synchronous function like this and expect it to work like a "normal" function. You need to design your code to deal with this situation, including the code that calls parseJSON - because the parsing might take several seconds so the code needs to wait. If your app has GUI then if you don't do this properly your whole application will hang and freeze.

Therefore when you write using asynchornicity your *entire* application has to be designed to deal with it properly.