# setting variable returned from rest request in objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rest

I'm making a rest call and returning lat longs with the call. For now I just return the coords passed because im just trying to learn the workings of objective C and iphone programing its been a few years. I have some code currently where I define some public vars that I set with in my rest function but when I go to draw them on a map they are 0 but if i break inside the function where im setting the label.text elements to the values they are set to the correct value but when it finishes the rest call they are reset. Not sure why

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  REST
//
//  Created by Grant Zukel on 8/5/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Grant Zukel. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
@import GoogleMaps;

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    @public NSInteger int_lat;
    @public NSInteger int_lon;
}



- (IBAction)drawMap;
{


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8001/test/39.748922&-104.986147"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                       NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];

             //NSLog([greeting objectForKey:@"status"]);
             self.greetingContent.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"content"];
             self.greetingId.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"];
             NSString *latitude = ([[greeting objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"latitude"]);
             NSString *longitude = ([[greeting objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"longitude"]);
             self.testLat.text = latitude;
             self.testLon.text = longitude;
             int_lat = [latitude intValue];
             int_lon = [longitude intValue];

         }
     }];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:int_lat
                                                            longitude:int_lon
                                                                 zoom:1];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(int_lat, int_lon);
    marker.title = @"Test";
    marker.snippet = @"Test";
    marker.map = mapView_;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self drawMap];
    //NSString *temperatureString = [self getStringForTemperature:A base:B];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I assume testLat and testLon are UILabels?  Did you instantiate them and add them to your view?

Comment: @joels yes you are correct that is my bad for not specifying that.

Comment: with your UILabels instantiated with appropriate frames, and added to the correct view, you are still not the correct lat and long values you're assigning to them after your url request?

Comment: @joels the labels are getting the correct values, but the int_lat, int_long that i set to publics are not getting set so when the map initializes it goes to the return coords from the reset call

Comment: Its because sendAsynchronousRequest is, as its name says, asynchronous but your code for drawMap is assuming it is synchronous.  See for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080642/contents-of-dictionary-not-accessible-outside-of-nsurlconnection-function/31080775#31080775